# Display few fields in encrypted format in VF page

Tags: visualforce

I am calling webservice in my Apex class.  I don't want to store the information in Salesforce. I am showing the information in VF page using wrapper class. But now i need to display few of the fields in encrypted format. Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to display them as if they had been stored as encrypted custom fields, or just that you want to display them in "an encrypted format" ?

Comment: just want to display them as encrypted format

Comment: Ok, cool. I have stuck what I hope is a useful answer on here :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Apex class providing information to a Visualforce page, and you wish to "encrypt" some of the fields before displaying them... could you use the Apex standard Crypto library?

You can read more on the [Crypto class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) in the docs. Note that in order to display the encrypted value of the string on the page I had to run it through the [Base64 encoding class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) too.

So as an example, if you had a super simple controller like:

```
public class HashMeUp() {

    public string myHash = 'Hello World!';

    public string getMyHash() {

        return EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256',
                                                                     Crypto.generateAesKey(256), 
                                                                     Blob.valueOf(String.valueOf(myHash))));
    }
```

and the accompanying Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="HashMeUp">

    <h1>{!myHash}</h1>

</apex:page>
```

You would not see "**Hello World!**" on your page, as you might expect from your variable instantiation, you would see this:

> **tgcwXMgmta06XPyYQWmSKU/NUmj8RIdHxpSWTXhCaG0=**

The encoded version of the string..

See:

[image: encrypted]

Is that sort of what you are after??

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Calm down @AtulRajguru9 - I explained what I was doing in the edit.

Comment: Super Kool.... This is exactly what i was looking for ...

Comment: fyi: In reference to your edit comment (chill pills :p) Simon, posts under a certain amount of characters are automatically flagged as "low quality" and get queued as such in the review queues.